# Sending mails from different mail servers in CRM 2011

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, smtpclient

Is possible to create more than one email profile on email router in Dynamic CRM 2011?
I want to send emails using different mail servers for different contacts in crm. How can I do this?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up multiple outgoing profiles in the E-Mail Router with different mail servers. This can be done on the Configuration Profiles tab. If you meant you wanted to send mail through different servers for different "users", you can specify which outgoing profile a "user" is assigned to on the Users, Queues, and Forward Mailboxes tab.